# Extracting nameservers from domain using DNSutil | type dns.RR has no field or method Hdr

Tags: go, dns

I am trying to extract the nameservers from a DNS record using GoLang. The issue I'm walking into is that I'm unable to read the fields from a Struct.

I'm turning the Response into JSON so I can "read" which fields it has, I'm using the following code for that:

```
json, _ := json.Marshal(ns)
fmt.Println(string(json))
```

This prints out:

```
{"Hdr":{"Name":"example.com.","Rrtype":2,"Class":1,"Ttl":172800,"Rdlength":16},"Ns":"ns2.example.eu."}
```

Now when I try to read print out the Name value from this string using:

```
fmt.Println(ns.Hdr.Name)
```

I get the following error:

```
./main.go:19:18: ns.Hdr undefined (type dns.RR has no field or method Hdr)
```

Could anyone help me to extract the Name (example.com.) from the Ns (Struct?).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lixiangzhong/dnsutil"
)

func main() {
    var dig dnsutil.Dig
    dig.SetDNS("8.8.4.4")

    res, _ := dig.Trace("example.com.")
    for _, nameservers := range res {
        for _, ns := range nameservers.Msg.Ns {
            json, _ := json.Marshal(ns)
            fmt.Println(string(json))
            fmt.Println(ns.Hdr.Name)
        }
    }
}
```

I expected this to print out "example.com." but instead I get an error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to avoid compilation error change Hdr to Header()

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/lixiangzhong/dnsutil"
)

func main() {
    var dig dnsutil.Dig
    dig.SetDNS("8.8.4.4")

    res, _ := dig.Trace("example.com.")
    for _, nameservers := range res {
        for _, ns := range nameservers.Msg.Ns {
            json, _ := json.Marshal(ns)
            fmt.Println(string(json))
            fmt.Println(ns.Header().Name)
        }
    }
}
```